# (treino/iniciante) Problema com segfault em fread() e fwrite() em .txt!

Tags: c, falha-de-segmentação

Opa, pessoal! 
 Primeiro queria dizer que sou bem iniciante e autodidata. Comecei com o CS50 e tô na caminhada, rs. Contextualizando o código: 1x na semana eu trabalho em uma feira de orgânicos e preciso constantemente anotar os produtos e a quantidade que eu pego. Porém, eu gostaria de criar uma tabela no R com isso pra poder trabalhar e estudar com elas, e pra isso eu quero criar uma automação em C que receba um arquivo .txt com essas duas ou três colunas e me devolve com um outro .txt que tenha " ; " entre os valores.

Exemplificando:

```
Input: mamão 2000 g 
Output: mamão ; 2000 ; g
```

Só isso!

Eu usei o fread() com um char *buffer que criei e aloquei memória com malloc e o fwrite() com outro char *buffer que eu gero a cópia modificada (em tese) com o que eu quero que ele faça no arquivo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


//função para descobrir o tamanho do arquivo
long int sizeOfFile (FILE *infile);

//vâm vê o que é isso aí ainda
void CriarTabela (char *text, char *modText);

//a ideia é ser nomeado o arquivo de entrada que deseja modificar e o nome em que o programa irá salvá-lo depois
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //avisa o usuário se o programa não for utilizado corretamente
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "./tabela_sc input.txt output.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //gravando os nomes dos arquivos
    char *infile = argv[1];
    char *outfile = argv[2];
    
    //abrindo arquivos de texto e criando nova tabela
    FILE *raw_table = fopen(infile, "r");    
    FILE *mod_table = fopen(outfile, "w");

    //se não houver memória, encerrar programa
    if (raw_table == NULL || mod_table == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Não há memória suficiente para realizar a operação!\n");
        return 2;
    }

    //descobrindo tamanho do arquivo para inicar array
    long int sf = sizeOfFile(raw_table); 
    
    //criando buffer array para armazenar o arquivo
    char *origTable = malloc(sizeof(sf));
    //criando +1000 bytes de memória para modificações (arbitrário)
    char *modTable = malloc(sizeof(sf + 1000));
    
    fread(origTable, sizeof(char), sf, raw_table);

    CriarTabela (origTable, modTable);

    
    fwrite(modTable, sizeof(char), sizeof(char), mod_table);
    
       
    fclose(raw_table);
    fclose(mod_table);
    free(origTable);
    free(modTable);

    return 0;
    
}

long int sizeOfFile (FILE *infile)
{
    fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_END);
    long int sf = ftell(infile);

    return sf;
} 

void CriarTabela (char *text, char *modText)
{
    int modificacoes = 0;

    for (int i = 0; text[i] != EOF; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            modText[i + modificacoes] = origText[i];
        }
        // se for um espaço em branco seguido/precedido por um caractere e seguido/precedido por um número, insira "; " e atualize o número de modificações feitas 
        else if ((isblank(origText[i]) && isalpha(origText[i - 1]) && isdigit(origText[i + 1])) || 
                (isblank(origText[i]) && isdigit(origText[i - 1]) && isalpha(origText[i + 1])))
        {
            modText[i + modificacoes] = origText[i];
            modText[i + 1 + modificacoes++] = ';';
            modText[i + 1 + modificacoes++] = ' ';
        }
        
        else
        {
            modText[i + modificacoes ] = origText[i];
            //teste
            printf("%c", origText[i]);
        }
    } 
}
```

Quando não funcionou, eu achei que era um problema com a lógica meio gambiarrística que eu tinha usado pra fazer essas modificações em CriarTabela(), mas parece que o problema está no char *buffer original. Então inseri um printf na função CriarTabela() pra ver o que acontecia e eis que vi esse seg fault.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que eu estou fazendo errado?

[image: segfault]

Comment: Aqui: `malloc(sizeof(sf));` você está alocando o tamanho de um long e não a quantidade de bytes indicada por sf. Como, pelo que entendi, seu arquivo de entrada pode conter linhas de comprimentos diversos será que não seria mais prático utilizar fgets/fputs e tratar as alterações linha a linha?